# How do I start silverlight on netflix in full screen automatically?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, htpc, fullscreen, silverlight

I know that there this great big button that I can click for full screen on the bottom left of the screen.  What I'm doing though is launching the direct movie/tv episode in chrome from XBMC using XBMCflicks.  It's like pasting the video html address in the address bar and going directly to the video feed.  Here's my dilemma, I want a fully working, no need for a keyboard/mouse HTPC, which means I don't want to have to click on the 'full screen' button.  Is there a way to run chrome and silverlight automatically in full screen mode when launched?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43724/how-to-view-netflix-watch-instantly-in-xbmc/) from How-To Geek will step you through installing XBMC Flicks. [This is the offical forum post.](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=87552)</strike>

> Overview:
>   Your Instant Queue in XBMC's GUI, with search, new listings and add/removing items from the Queue (Instant and Disc Queue is supported).
>
> This is using the Netflix API with version 2.0 calls. It's registered with Netflix as xbmcflicks.

This will not make Netflix fullscreen in XBMC. [This guide](http://forum.xbmc.org/archive/index.php/t-98829.html) seems like a good workaround.

Comment: That's great, but I already know how to install and run XBMCflicks on XBMC.  What it does is create an instance of IE that run separate and pulls up the netflix.  What it doesn't do, is start up silverlight in full screen automatically.

Comment: The link doesn't work.